# How to pass Android intent to anyone but my own app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc

I have a certain intent (`NDEF_DISCOVERED`), some of which I cannot handle correctly, so I want to redirect those to android's default nfc handler.

So i take the intent, `setComponent(null)`, and then `startActivity(intent)`

But.. it always comes back to my app in an infinite loop of intent throwing.

Is there a way I can send off an intent to anyone but my app? Or send it to android's default nfc handler?

EDIT: 
So I used vikram's answer to query the packagemanager for possible activities to handle my intent, then looped thru and found the activity with the highest priority (who isn't me) and sent an explicit intent to them.

Comment: May be this helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615240/start-an-android-app-intent-from-an-nfc-tag?rq=1

Comment: `But.. it always comes back to my app in an infinite loop of intent throwing`  What exactly do you mean?  Please show the code where you create the intent and your manifest.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  What *exactly* do you mean by infinite loop?  You have shown no code which could result in an infinite loop.

Comment: I send off the intent (for which I have `setComponent(null)` so it does not explicitly come back to me.)
Then android, because it auto-chooses the best NFC app to handle the intent, keeps choosing mine, and my app keeps receiving the intent and sending it back off forever.

Not a conventional infinite-loop as seen within code. But rather a loop as in back-and-forth intent-passing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A custom chooser dialog/popup will be better for you in this case. Instead of launching an intent, use the `PackageManager` to `queryIntentActivities(Intent, int)`. From the `List<ResolveInfo>` that `queryIntentActivities(Intent, int)` returns, filter out your own app using the `packageName`:

```
String packageName = "";
for(ResolveInfo resInfo : resolvedInfoList) {

    packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;

    // Exclude `packageName` from the dialog/popup that you show

}
```

**Edit 1**:

The following code will create and show a `PopupWindow` whenever `showList()` is called. The xml layout file used to return `popupView` contains nothing but a `LinearLayout`(R.layout.some_popup_view):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/llPopup"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

This code is just a simple demonstration. For it to be anything close to usable, you will probably need to add a `ListView` with a custom adapter to this `PopupWindow`. In the `OnClickListener` for the `ListView`, you will retrieve the package name of the Application that the user clicks on, and generate an intent to start that activity. As of now, the code only displays how to filter out your own application using a custom chooser. In the `if` block, replace `"com.example.my.package.name"` with your app's package name.

```
public void showList() { 

    View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.some_popup_view, null);

    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout llPopup = (LinearLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.llPopup);

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    // In my case, NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED was not returning anything
    //intent.setAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    intent.setAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);

    List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    String packageName = "";

    for(ResolveInfo resInfo : resolvedInfoList) {

        packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;

        // Exclude `packageName` from the dialog/popup that you show
        if (!packageName.equals("com.example.my.package.name")) {

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);

            tv.setText(packageName);

            llPopup.addView(tv);
        }            

    }

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: So I can create the chooser instead of android doing it?

How would I do the whole process? If you could, can you show me exactly what I need to write? How do I "exclude" my name for example?

Comment: Also, once an NFC chooser popup appeared for me, because I had 2 nfc readers installed, but it only showed those two. I don't know if android's default nfc reader would show up in a chooser.

Comment: @ginsunuva I won't be able to update my answer right now as I'm busy. I'll leave a comment when I do.

Comment: @ginsunuva See **Edit 1** above.

Comment: Oh thanks, wow, I didn't know I'd have to build a chooser.
But instead I decided I will user the PackageManager and just read through the pending activities, and if mine is the only one, to not even start a new activity.

Comment: Or, would you happen to know anything about invoking android's default Nfc Service?

Comment: @ginsunuva I don't think there's a `default Nfc Service`(I could be wrong here). Take a look at [The Tag Dispatch System](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#tag-dispatch) and [How NFC Tags are Dispatched to Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#dispatching).

Comment: When I scan a tag that my app cannot read, it defaults to an application (or service, idk) called `Nfc Service` or redirects to the browser depending on the mime type (I think someone redirects it to browser because browser itself never shows up to handle any type of nfc intent in a chooser popup).

Answer (score 1):

there is also another option than to do a own chooser here ( different looking chooser might confuse the user )

```
public void rethrowIntentExcludingSelf() {
    final ComponentName component = new ComponentName(this, getClass());
    this.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    final Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    intent.setComponent(null);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                }
            },250);
}
```

I am using it - and it works fine - just do not like this magic constant 250 - but do not yet see another way.