# Using Activity as a Dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, popup

i want use popup . i wrote a piece of code using intent i want to convert it to popup.

here is my code below :

```
ArrayList<String> contactList = new ArrayList<String>();

    switch (reqCode) {
    case (0):
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null,
                    null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String name = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                String contact = name + phoneNumber;

                contactList.add(contact);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Contacts", contactList);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7498695/2345913)

Comment: See if this helps: [How to pass Android intent to anyone but my own app?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17866142/2558882)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 1):

Create your activity as a Dialog

```
<activity
        android:name="OrderActivity"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
        >
    </activity>
```

and for removing title of the Activity Dialog- write this before setcontentview-

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: thanks @tarun Droid. one more question how can i get the selected contact name and show in a textbox ??

Comment: pass it through intent as you are doing.

Comment: Everything remains same in your code, except above changes in manifest. and your activity will become dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Below code will help you.. 

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Contacts");
    builder.setAdapter(new ContactListAdapter(),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    String contact = contactList.get(which);
                    Log.e("onClick", "Selected contact " + contact);
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    alertDialog.show();

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "AlertDialog.show");
```