# Android - NFC string into Textview

Tags: android, textview, nfc

I have created a simple app which the user can search for a room and then presses the search button to search for the room.

My next task is to have NFC so that the NFC stores the room in text format (Room 101) and when the user taps the tag it opens the app and inserts Room 101 into the textview.

Is this possible? And if it is can you provide some guidance?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can reference what is being communicated in this [response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615240/start-an-android-app-intent-from-an-nfc-tag) as to what steps to look into for starting an application from an NFC tag.

NFC tags can hold the text that you are referring to and pass it along to the application that it launched.  You would then be able to do what you would like inside your application.

This is similar to and intent-filter that you can manipulate with a program of your own based on an event in the hardware.  You can also look into intent filters and their associated meta-data fields to accomplish a task such as this.  Hopefully [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) will get you started on it.